# ASCX control not visible in design mode in VS2008

Tags: .net, asp.net, visual-studio-2008, ascx

I have a custom ASCX control that is not visible in design mode in VS2008.
It used to be, I changed nothing and now when I switch back to design mode, it is not visible.
Has anyone ever face this situation?

Comment: Yeah, I've tried it all, ironically the control appears in the page that uses it so for now, I've been refreshing that :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually this will occur if you have bad tags in your ASCX file.  Do this, open the ASCX (not the code-behind file) and hit CTRL+K then CTRL+D.  That will reformat the tags cleanly.  If you get an error, find it and fix it and it should resolve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Is that possible to post the code for the control?

Have you tried restarting Visual Studio?

What else is on the page where you are dropping the user control?